# Compiler error with Prisma

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma

I'm preparing a project with `GraphQL` server, using `Prisma` to connect with the database, all this with `Typscript`.

And the compiler is returning me :

Error: Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:management:cjkzo60s4000e0a01tuoln3l4: {"response":{"data":{"deploy":null},"errors":[{"message":"Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:management:cjkzo60s4000e0a01tuoln3l4","path":["deploy"],"locations":[{"line":2,"column":9}],"requestId":"local:management:cjkzo60s4000e0a01tuoln3l4"}],"status":200},"request":{"query":"      mutation($name: String!, $stage: String! $types: String! $dryRun: Boolean $secrets: [String!], $subscriptions: [FunctionInput!], $force: Boolean) {\n        deploy(input: {\n          name: $name\n          stage: $stage\n          types: $types\n          dryRun: $dryRun\n          secrets: $secrets\n          subscriptions: $subscriptions\n          force: $force\n        }) {\n          errors {\n            type\n            field\n            description\n          }\n          warnings {\n            type\n            field\n            description\n          }\n          migration {\n            ...MigrationFragment\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      \nfragment MigrationFragment on Migration {\n  revision\n  steps {\n    type\n    __typename\n    ... on CreateEnum {\n      name\n      ce_values: values\n    }\n    ... on CreateField {\n      model\n      name\n      cf_typeName: typeName\n      cf_isRequired: isRequired\n      cf_isList: isList\n      cf_isUnique: unique\n      cf_relation: relation\n      cf_defaultValue: default\n      cf_enum: enum\n    }\n    ... on CreateModel {\n      name\n    }\n    ... on CreateRelation {\n      name\n      leftModel\n      rightModel\n    }\n    ... on DeleteEnum {\n      name\n    }\n    ... on DeleteField {\n      model\n      name\n    }\n    ... on DeleteModel {\n      name\n    }\n    ... on DeleteRelation {\n      name\n    }\n    ... on UpdateEnum {\n      name\n      newName\n      values\n    }\n    ... on UpdateField {\n      model\n      name\n      newName\n      typeName\n      isRequired\n      isList\n      isUnique: unique\n      relation\n      default\n      enum\n    }\n    ... on UpdateModel {\n      name\n      um_newName: newName\n    }\n  }\n}\n\n    ","variables":{"name":"default","stage":"default","types":"enum UserType {\n    CUSTOMER\n    MAKER\n    ADMIN\n}\n\n\nenum OfferType {\n    NORMAL\n    LTS\n}\n\n\nenum DesignType {\n    MUSIC\n    GRAPHIC_ART\n    PIXEL_ART\n    MOTION_DESIGN\n}\n\nenum StoryType {\n    SMALL\n    LONG\n}\n\ninterface Account {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    registered: Boolean! @default(value: \"false\")\n    contacts: [Account!]!\n    address: Address\n    favorite: [Service!]!\n}\n\ntype Address {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    city: String!\n    country: String!\n    street: String\n    houseNumber: String\n    phoneNumber: String\n}\n\ntype User implements Account {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    registered: Boolean! @default(value: \"false\")\n    contacts: [Account!]!\n    address: Address\n    favorite: [Service!]!\n    gender: Gender\n    personalData: PersonalData\n    type: UserType\n}\n\ntype PersonalData {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    firstName: String\n    lastName: String!\n    email: String!\n}\n\ntype Organisation implements Account {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    registered: Boolean! @default(value: \"false\")\n    contacts: [Account!]!\n    address: Address\n    favorite: [Service!]!\n    responsible: User\n}\n\ntype Payment {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    date: DateTime!\n    price: Int!\n}\n\ntype Purchase {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    payment: Payment!\n    seller: Account!\n    buyer: Account!\n    services: [Service!]!\n}\n\ntype Offer {\n    price: Int!\n    type: OfferType\n}\n\ninterface Service {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    creationDate: DateTime!\n    updateDate: DateTime!\n    comments: [Comment!]!\n    author: Account!\n    offer: Offer\n}\n\ntype Design implements Service {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    creationDate: DateTime!\n    updateDate: DateTime!\n    comments: [Comment!]!\n    author: Account!\n    offer: Offer\n    type: [DesignType!]!\n}\n\ntype Story implements Service {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    creationDate: DateTime!\n    updateDate: DateTime!\n    comments: [Comment!]!\n    author: Account!\n    offer: Offer\n    endDate: DateTime!\n    type: [StoryType!]!\n}\n\ntype Comment {\n    id: ID! @unique\n    author: Account! @relation(name: \"Writer\")\n    service: Service!\n}\n\n","secrets":null,"subscriptions":[]}}}
    at GraphQLClient. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/graphql-request/src/index.ts:72:13)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/src/index.js:40:23)
    at Object.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/src/index.js:21:53)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prisma/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/src/index.js:12:58)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)

I hope you could read, and also hope someone can help me!

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: related issue [link](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-server-example/issues/79)

Comment: Thanks! Came through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was related to an [issue](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-prisma-typescript/issues/79), which yet is being closed.

Nice day to you all!